# How to load saved data after login in parse unity

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I just started exploring Parse for Unity. I have a couple of questions:

1. Is `signUp` equal to `login`? What I want to know is, if I signup do I need to login?
2. After I login, I create a save object, lets say `Scores`. How do I get this object back just after I login. If I hard code the object ID in `GetAsync` it works fine. I am sure this is not the right way.

Can someone please guide me on this?